# Where to put scratch file to be able to access Model data/methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file that I use for testing ideas and ensuring a code refactor is working. I'd like to be able to access my `Shop` Model data from within this scratch file. For instance I'd like to be able to do this in the `tester.rb` file:

```
pp Shop.all
```

Where would I put it, and what should it inherit from in order for it to work? I've tried the following with no success.
I put a `tester.rb` file in the `models` folder and tried inheriting from:

```
class Tester < Shop
class Tester < ActiveRecord::Base
```

And yes I can use `pry` or `irb` but my testing involves more than a couple lines of code, and a console gets messy fast.

Thanks

Comment: By convention, one uses tests to verify that a refactor has worked.  If you're refactoring without tests, you're just changing stuff.  That said...why not just smoke test your code in its natural habitat?  That is to say, run through what you expect your code to do manually to verify it instead of having to fiddle with other files and what not.

Comment: I think of this as a draft of code, like writing a paper. I'll write some code, see if it works, does what I want, see if there is a better way. All in isolation, so I know that other code isn't effecting it. In the end, if I like it and it does what I want. Then I put it into my dev environment to refactor/test whatever else. Its the way I've found that works best for me.

Comment: I'd recommend version control and branching in this scenario.  There are more effective and efficient ways to achieve your aims, and all they involve is one or two extra bits of knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use [Pry's `play` command](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/User-Input#Play).

What I do for testing things out or writing one-off scripts is:

1. Create a a folder in my project root called `rcs` (short for "Rails Console Scripts")
2. Add that path to *.gitignore* so it won't be added to version control
3. Add test code to a well-named file in */rcs* and play it back in the Pry / Rails Console session as needed

Protip: The first line of your RCS script should always be `reload!` so that when you play it back you reload the console and get a fresh play of your script.

#### Example rcs script:

```
# /rcs/bm.rb

reload!

Benchmark.bmbm { |x|
  iterations = 10_000_000
  x.report("double quotes") {
    iterations.times do |i|
      "hi"
    end
  }
  x.report("single quotes") {
    iterations.times do |i|
      'hi'
    end
  }
}
```

#### Example .gitignore entry:

```
rcs/
```

#### Example invocation in Rails Console:

```
play rcs/bm.rb
```

---

In your case, you might want to make */rcs/shop_test.rb* and just monkey patch your Shop class. For example:

```
reload!

class Shop
  def my_method
    # Do something special
  end
end

shop = Shop.new
shop.my_method
```

Then just call `play rcs/shop_test.rb` from the Rails console each time you make an edit to */rcs/shopt_test.rb* to see the new output/results.

Comment: Perfect.. Exactly what I was looking for!!